# localhost 500 internal server

Tags: server, apache2

Yesterday localhost is still work, but this morning localhost is down with 500 internal server error.

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
```

Here the logs:

```
/var/log/apache2/error.log
[Tue Dec 17 11:44:36 2013] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] /.htaccess: Invalid command 'disable', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration


access.log
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2013:11:44:36 +0700] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 630 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.65 Safari/537.36"
```

My `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       asus
127.0.1.1       kd.com
127.0.1.1       www.kd.com
127.0.1.1       angga.net
127.0.1.1       www.angga.net
127.0.1.1       www.dok.com
127.0.1.1       dok.com
```

i was tried this :

```
root ~ #  a2enmod rewrite
Module rewrite already enabled


root ~ #  a2enmod
Your choices are: actions alias asis auth_basic auth_digest authn_alias authn_anon authn_dbd authn_dbm authn_default authn_file authnz_ldap authz_dbm authz_default authz_groupfile authz_host authz_owner authz_user autoindex cache cern_meta cgi cgid charset_lite dav dav_fs dav_lock dbd deflate dir disk_cache dump_io env expires ext_filter file_cache filter headers ident imagemap include info ldap log_forensic mem_cache mime mime_magic negotiation php5 proxy proxy_ajp proxy_balancer proxy_connect proxy_ftp proxy_http proxy_scgi reqtimeout rewrite setenvif speling ssl status substitute suexec unique_id userdir usertrack version vhost_alias
Which module(s) do you want to enable (wildcards ok)?
rewrite
Module rewrite already enabled
```

And this is my spec :

```
root ~ #  uname -a
Linux asus 3.8.0-35-generic #50~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 4 17:25:51 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

root ~ #  php -v
PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.9 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Dec 12 2013 04:27:25) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies

root ~ #  apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Jul 12 2013 13:37:10

root ~ #  mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.34-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

EDIT I :
There is no `.htaccess` in my `/var/www/` dir.

EDIT 2 :

here is my apache2.conf

http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/13G7

and here for ls -al /var/www

http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/13H7

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. The error log mentions that there is a problem with a ".htaccess"-file. Files that begin with a dot are hidden by default. Open nautilus and press Crtl + h to show those hidden files. Navigate to /var/www and have a look if there is a ".htaccess"-file.

Comment: 1. Can you post your apache configuration, maybe your config doesn't point to `/var/www/`. 2. list the folder with `ls -a /var/www/` in the terminal, `.htaccess`-files are "hidden" dot-files, maybe your filemanger doesn't list them...

Comment: i was edit the question. but like i said before. there is no .htaccess in my /var/www dir. i was check it via file manager by pressing ctrl+h for display hidden file/dir but there is no .htaccess .

Comment: This helped me too. From now on error logs are my favorite thing! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this solved.
today i was tried all ways to fix this problem, finaly i remove apache2, than reinstall again. but when i edit `000-default` file, i see .htaccess in my `/` root dir, so i rename the file then i restore my dummy TLD domain, and its work.
thanks for adv.

Comment: Please accept this answer so this issue can be closed. The community bot has bumped this question back to the front page.